# Relationships with Authority in jhipster

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

I generated a new jhipster server side and I want to add more fields to Authority entity or Add relationships OneToOne but I got this error :

`An error occured while running jhipster:entity#loadRelationships ERROR! Error looking for otherEntity Authority at AuthorityLabel,User,AuthorityUser,UserInfo Error: Error looking for otherEntity Authority at AuthorityLabel,User,AuthorityUser,UserInfo at /home/bousra/bousra-angular-project/backend/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/index.js:614:19 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at EntityGenerator.loadRelationships (/home/bousra/bousra-angular-project/backend/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/index.js:610:36) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bousra/bousra-angular-project/backend/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1091:23) at /home/bousra/bousra-angular-project/backend/node_modules/run-async/index.js:49:25 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at /home/bousra/bousra-angular-project/backend/node_modules/run-async/index.js:26:19 at /home/bousra/bousra-angular-project/backend/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1092:9 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at EntityGenerator.executeTask (/home/bousra/bousra-angular-project/backend/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1063:12)`

Thanks for help

I tried to generate the other by using

```
jhipster entity AuthorityLabel, After that I choose adding relationship but i get the error described.
THANKS FOR HELP
```